# Automatically convert RelaxNG schema to an editable GUI

Tags: user-interface, editor, validation, relaxng

I have a RelaxNG schema and I'd like to create documents conforming to the schema, but using the schema to derive a GUI (preferably Java) that would contain fields corresponding to elements of the schema. Each field would be associated with a 'validator' that enforces the constraints for that element as specified in the schema. Note - this is not deriving a GUI from an XML definition of a GUI. Rather I'm trying to automatically generate a GUI editor that allows one to generate documents that conform to the schema.

Are there Open Source tools that are capable of this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any out-of-the-box solution out there to do that. If you want to build that on your own, I'd suggest using rngom http://java.net/projects/rngom as a starting point. With rngom you can parse the RelaxNG schema and generate an object model out of it. 
It should not be hard to generate some kind of GUI out of the generated object model.

Unfortunately, there is no documentation at all about how to use rngom, thats why I posted this rngom-related question: [Generate object model out of RelaxNG schema with RNGOM - how to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607715/generate-object-model-out-of-relaxng-schema-with-rngom-how-to-start)
The only thing I know is that the Glassfish guys use it to generate an object model for the [libvirt domain.xml RelaxNG schema](http://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=tree;f=docs/schemas;hb=HEAD) (but I could not find out how yet).